# Chef : NameError : Uninitialized constant curstom resource

Tags: chef-infra, element, nameerror, rexml, uninitialized-constant

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRXaX.png)

Can someone tell me what can be the causes of this error. Does this mean it needs initialization before actually using it? My resource uses REXML::Element where it is throwing error, although the values have been supplied it is throwing uninitialized error.

Thanks.